# For-Each Loop Misses First Index When Multiple Indices Exist

Tags: php, loops, foreach, explode

I've got the below PHP which works great when the array of locations only have 1 value, but when it has any number more than 1, the information on the first location keeps printing out blank. The array is set by calling `explode` on a comma-delimited list. When I set the array manually immediately before the loop, it works great! Yet not when I use `explode`, even though I printed the array and can confirm it's getting set up just as I expect (with the correct 0 index). The code I have is:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($locations as &$value) 
{
    $locationDetails = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM locations WHERE id='$value'");
    $locationDetailRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($locationDetails);

    echo "<li>".$locationDetailRow['name']."</li>";
}
unset($value);
echo "</ul>";
```

I've confirmed that the query does not fail, that `$value` is what I expect it to be, and that the `name` does exist for the first `$value` in every case.

Any reason this should be failing on the first case when there are multiple locations?

Comment: It's quite inefficient making `count($locations)` queries, don't you think? Why can't you just use a single query - and parse the response according to `id` column?

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: You can keep your comma separated list and change your query to: `WHERE id IN (4, 6, 9)`. Then you would only need one query.